# Calculate height from tangent of a point on the circumference of a circle

Tags: trigonometry, circles, tangent-line

I have a mechanical press which uses rotary eccentric gears and plungers to translate rotation into a linear movement of fixed length, or stroke. The machine moves linearly to a maximum distance of 500mm.

I've drawn the system out in CAD, to scale, and measured the heights manually.

[CAD Drawing with measurements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzJIb.png)

Measurements:

| Angle (degrees) | Distance (slide Stroke mm) |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 10 | 4.03 |
| 20 | 16.11 |
| 30 | 32.59 |
| 40 | 58.23 |
| 50 | 87.85 |
| 60 | 124.57 |
| 70 | 162.01 |
| 80 | 205.55 |
| 90 | 250 |

What i've been trying to figure out, is the mathematical relationship to calculate that stroke (height from the tangent of the circle i think?) for any angle of the circle.

I can obviously see the relationship between radius and height, but can't figure out how to incorporate the angle into the equation.

By graphing stroke against angle, I see it trends a sine wave:

[Sine Wave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjhPF.png)

but doing something like 500 * sin(theta) doesn't get me near.

Looking for some feedback on how to calculate this measured value please

Comment: Try $250\cdot(1-\cos\theta)$

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Yep! this is it. Thank you! As a follow up for my learning, what is the purpose of subtracting the cosine of theta from 1?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0puz.jpg